# Symbol interposition on macOS

Tags: c, gcc, clang, function-interposition, library-interposition

I have a program that links against a shared library `libfoo`. I want to override one of the functions from `libfoo` inside my program, such that internal calls to that function from within `libfoo` resolve to the definition in my program. (For context, my intention is to mock out the library function for testing.)

This question is kind of related to this one: [symbol lookup in shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747821/symbol-lookup-in-shared-libraries). This is the example from that question:

```c
// foo.c
void dispatch_write_hello(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "hello\n");
}

void print_hello(void) {
    dispatch_write_hello();
}

// main.c
extern void print_hello(void);

void dispatch_write_hello(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "overridden\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    print_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what it does on linux:

```
$ clang -shared -fPIC foo.c -o libfoo.so
$ clang main.c -L. -lfoo
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
overridden
```

This is the behavior I want, but on macOS I get this:

```
$ clang -dynamiclib -fPIC foo.c -o libfoo.dylib
$ clang main.c -L. -lfoo
$ ./a.out
hello
```

How can I achieve the behavior of the linux example on macOS? Preferably I'd like one approach that works on both linux and macOS, but I guess it's okay if I need to use macOS-specific build flags and/or environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by adding `-Wl,-flat_namespace` when building the library.

(I also tried some other folklore from the internet including `-Wl,-force_flat_namespace` when linking the program, or running the program with `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1`, but neither seemed to work.)